# CakePHP pagination numbers()

Tags: cakephp, pagination, helper

CakePHP Pagination Helper has function numbers() for generation pages links.

I would like generate numbers (default 8) with class 'numbers' and additionally class to first number and last number ('number-first' and 'number-last').
My question is how add class to first and last number?

OR

How to generate numbers from 2 to 7. When I generate this numbers i use first() and last().

Sorry, but my english is very simple:)

Answer (score -1):

For adding a class to all number links, there is already an option for [that](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-page-number-links):

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('class' => 'numbers'));
```

If I understood what you want to accomplish, you should do something like this:

```
echo $this->Paginator->first(__('<< First'), array('class' => 'number-first'));
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('class' => 'numbers', 'first' => false, 'last' => false));
echo $this->Paginator->last(__('>> Last'), array('class' => 'number-last'));
```

If this is not what you wanted, you'll have to make your own pagination helper and extend the existing one to override the `numbers()` method.

Comment: @kicaj: Well that's strange..accoriding to the code I'm reading, it should work. If that's true, you're out of luck and will need to extend the PaginatorHelper, and write some code yourself.

Comment: can you pls tell me how can i achive this with dropdown not list